# Snapd Auto-Refreshing libreoffice for the last 4 days

Tags: libreoffice, snap

My disk activity light has been flashng at warp speed for days through multiple reboots.  iotop shows that snapd is writing to the disk (an expensive SSD, I might add) continuously.  Snap changes shows *48 Doing   4 days ago, at 10:53 EDT  - Auto-refresh snap "libreoffice"".  But snap refresh says "All snaps are up to date."

Something appears to be stuck, how do I unstuck it before it trashes my SSD?  I'm beginning to understand why some people are not fond of snaps.

Comment: Why not just remove this snap and reinstall?

Comment: You can use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-7-0) if you want to use Libreoffice 7 without using snap.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:  I was able to abort the refresh ("snap abort 48").  Running `snap refresh` now returns `All snaps up to date`.  I have no idea what it was doing.

Edit:  Well after a reboot it is back.  Will remove and install with Apt tomorrow.  Thanks for the PPA.

Well, nothing is easy.  Aborted the auto-refresh, `snap changes` shows it as aborted.  `sudo snap remove libreoffice` returns an `error: snap "libreoffice" has "auto-refresh" change in progress`.  Yes, that is why I am trying to remove it.  `Snap refresh` still shows `All snaps up to date`.

Open the Ubuntu Software store and try to remove it from there, same error.  Tried updating it from the store, the Update button changes to Installing for about 3 seconds, then goes back to Update.

Did a bit of Googling and it seems there is no way to force the removal of a snap that has an auto-refresh in progress.

`snap tasks` on the ID for the task showed that it was doing the download, but stuck at 29.5 %.  I stopped and started snapd, and it finished!  Removing libreoffice now,I will reinstall using apt.